# Creating a value in json only if the key exists using Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I am new to Jolt,
I am trying to transform JSON to a particular format, where i am moving some objects into another object, I think i am close.

This is my JSON

```
{
 "relatedParty": [
   {
     "id": "B2BSmallandMedium"
   }
 ],
 "serviceOrderItem": [
   {
     "id": "e26205f4-e144-4ded-9e64-82ede0b26f4",
     "action": "add",
     "service": {
       "name": "cust",
       "state": "active",
       "supportingService": [
         {
           "id": "e26205f4-e144-4ded-9e64-82ede0b26e99",
           "href": "serviceInventory/v4/service"
         },
         {
           "id": "7313c885-a075-4188-a6bc-c3fbfb4c7422",
           "href": "activationAndConfiguration/v4/service"
         }
       ]
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

I am using the JOLT

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "relatedParty": "relatedParty",
      "serviceOrderItem": {
        "*": {
          "id": "serviceOrderItem[&1].id",
          "action": "serviceOrderItem[&1].action",
          "service": {
            "*": "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.&",
            "#modifyPath": "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.serviceCharacteristic[0].name",
            "@(1,modifyPath)": "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.serviceCharacteristic[0].value",
            "#supportingService": "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.serviceCharacteristic[1].name",
            "@(1,service.supportingService)": "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.serviceCharacteristic[1].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "serviceOrderItem": {
        "*": {
          "service": {
            "supportingService": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
}]
```

which gives me the output

```
{
  "relatedParty" : [ {
    "id" : "B2BSmallandMedium"
  } ],
  "serviceOrderItem" : [ {
    "action" : "add",
    "id" : "e26205f4-e144-4ded-9e64-82ede0b26f4",
    "service" : {
      "name" : "cust",
      "serviceCharacteristic" : [ {
        "name" : "modifyPath"
      }, {
        "name" : "supportingService",
        "value" : [ {
          "href" : "serviceInventory/v4/service",
          "id" : "e26205f4-e144-4ded-9e64-82ede0b26e99"
        }, {
          "href" : "activationAndConfiguration/v4/service",
          "id" : "7313c885-a075-4188-a6bc-c3fbfb4c7422"
        } ]
      } ],
      "state": "active"
    }
  } ]
}
```

but in the output, there is an element **name:modifyPath** which is not needed for this json.

Is it possible to create the **name:"modifyPath"** or **name:"supportingService"**

> "#modifyPath":
> "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.serviceCharacteristic[0].name"

only if the respective objects are available in the input and not otherwise?

I am not sure on how to use default,
I tried,

```
{
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "serviceOrderItem": {
        "*": {
          "service": {
            "serviceCharacteristic[0].value": "test"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I think I solved it, I was working with **operation:default** instead of **modify-default-beta**

```
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "serviceOrderItem": {
        "*": {
          "service": {
            "serviceCharacteristic": {
              "*": {
                "value": "[]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

this is now giving me

```
    "service" : {
      "name" : "cust",
      "serviceCharacteristic" : [ {
        "name" : "modifyPath",
        "value" : "[]"
      }, {
        "name" : "supportingService",
        "value" : [ {
          "href" : "serviceInventory/v4/service",
          "id" : "e26205f4-e144-4ded-9e64-82ede0b26e99"
        }, {
          "href" : "activationAndConfiguration/v4/service",
          "id" : "7313c885-a075-4188-a6bc-c3fbfb4c7422"
        } ]
      } ],
      "state" : "active"
    }
  } ]
```

This is working for me.

I would still like to know if it is possible  replace

> "#modifyPath":
> "serviceOrderItem[&2].service.serviceCharacteristic[0].name"

to update the Json only when the key is actually available.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. There is already no such **name**s within the provided input. Can you please update with the cases( complete inputs and desired outputs ) based on existence of those values for the **name**s ?